# How do have the same drawn object appear at the same time? (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, draw, rect

I'm trying to get the red rectangle (note) to show up more than once on the screen instead of having only 1 rectangle appear at one time. Is there any way I could achieve this without creating multiple identical rectangles and deleting more code? I'm a beginner to pygame so a simple answer would definitely be appreciated.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

cont = True
delNote = False
delUser = False
delScoreUpdate = False
reset = False

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
userColor = (0, 255, 0)
grey = (224, 224, 224)

displayX = 800
displayY = 600

noteY = -600

currentScore = 0

speed = 5

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayX, displayY))

pygame.display.set_caption("game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def drawUser():
    user = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, userColor, [375, 430, 50, 50])

def drawNote():
    note = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [385, noteY, 30, 30])

def crashDisplay():
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    text = font.render(str(currentScore), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [150, 200])

def scoreUpdate():
    fontS = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
    textS = fontS.render(str(currentScore), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(textS, [0, 0])

while cont is True:

    if reset is True:
        reset = False
        delNote = False

    gameDisplay.fill(grey)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and noteY > 420 and noteY < 490:
                delNote = True
                reset = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 userColor = (0, 150, 0)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                userColor = (0, 255, 0)

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            cont = False

    if delScoreUpdate is False:
        scoreUpdate()

    if delUser is False:
        drawUser()

    if delNote is False:
        noteY += speed
        drawNote()

    if reset is True:
        noteY = -600
        noteY += speed

    if noteY > 600:
        delUser = True
        delScoreUpdate = True
        delNote = True
        crashDisplay()

    pygame.display.update()

    if delScoreUpdate is False:
        clock.tick(60)
        currentScore += 0.1
        currentScore = round(currentScore, 4)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a list with the note positions (`notes`) and iterate over this list in your while loop to move and draw the notes and also for the collision detection in the event loop.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

cont = True
red = (255, 0, 0)
userColor = (0, 255, 0)
grey = (224, 224, 224)
speed = 5
notes = [0, 100, 200]

while cont:
    # Event handling.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                userColor = (0, 150, 0)
                # Use enumerate to get the index and the
                # item at the same time.
                for i, noteY in enumerate(notes):
                    # If the player rect collides with a note.
                    if noteY > 420 and noteY < 490:
                        notes[i] -= 660  # Reset the position.
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                userColor = (0, 255, 0)
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            cont = False

    # Game logic.
    for i in range(len(notes)):  # Loop over the notes.
        notes[i] += speed  # Move the note.
        if notes[i] >= 600:  # If below the screen ...
            notes[i] -= 660  # reset the position.

    # Draw everything.
    gameDisplay.fill(grey)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, userColor, [375, 430, 50, 50])
    for noteY in notes:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [385, noteY, 30, 30])

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

You could also put [`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) into the list instead of just the y-position. They have some handy collision detection methods and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little late but this is for others if they have same problem.

Check if red block is out of screen with something like if y coordinate of the block is > than display height then,
y coordinate = 0 (or -60 or something to make it like its coming from up)